# Am inserting values into four tables simultaneously using output parameter bt only one table is getting value

Tags: stored-procedures

```
USE [ctsdev]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_insertemployeeinfo]    Script Date: 03/24/2016 11:33:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insertemployeeinfo]
@Emp_id int ,
@FirstName varchar(100),
@MiddleName varchar(50),
@LastName varchar(100),
@Date_of_join date,
@Job_title varchar(50),
@Grade varchar(50),
@Department varchar(50),
@Location varchar(100),
@Date_of_birth date,
@Nationality varchar(100),
@Mobile_no varchar(10),
@Psprt_yn varchar(1),
@Passport_no varchar(8),
@Date_of_issue date,
@Place_of_issue varchar(100),
@Date_of_expiry date,
@Pancard_yn varchar(1),
@Pancard_no varchar(10),
@Relatives_yn varchar(1),
@Relative_name varchar(100),
@Relative_grade varchar(100),
@Relative_dept varchar(100), /*1st table*/

@Home_adrs varchar(max),
@Home_number varchar(10),
@Home_mailid varchar(100),
@CHA_PHA_same varchar(1),
@Contact_name varchar(100),
@Relation varchar(100),
@City varchar(100),
@Contact_adrs varchar(100),
@Contact_num varchar(100), /*2nd table*/

@Qualification varchar(100),
@University_board varchar(100),
@Specialization varchar(100),
@Year_of_passing date,
@Grade_cgpa varchar(20), /*3rd table*/

@Bank_name varchar(100),
@Bank_adrs varchar(100),
@Account_num varchar(50),
@Ifsc_code varchar(50),
@Name_of_acnt_holder varchar(100), /*4th table*/

@From_date date,
@To_date date,
@Organization varchar(100),
@Job_title_his varchar(50),
@Sal_per_mnth varchar (50),
@Reasons_for_leavn varchar(max),
@Reference_name varchar(100),
@Contact_num_hist varchar(10),
@Organization_ref varchar(100),
@Job_title_ref varchar(50), /*5th table*/

@newid int output
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

/* INSERTING INTO 1ST TABLE*/ 
INSERT INTO [tbl_empinfo ](FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Date_of_join,Job_title,Grade,Department,Location,Date_of_birth,Nationality,Mobile_no,Psprt_yn,Passport_no,Date_of_issue, Place_of_issue,Date_of_expiry, Pancard_yn,Pancard_no,Relatives_yn, Relative_name, Relative_grade,Relative_dept )
VALUES      (@FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName,@Date_of_join,@Job_title,@Grade,@Department,@Location,@Date_of_birth,@Nationality,@Mobile_no,@Psprt_yn,@Passport_no,@Date_of_issue,@Place_of_issue,@Date_of_expiry,@Pancard_yn,@Pancard_no,@Relatives_yn,@Relative_name,@Relative_grade,@Relative_dept)
SELECT @Emp_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
SELECT @Emp_id As newid
RETURN  

/*SELECT @identity=SCOPE_IDENTITY()*/
/* INSERTING INTO 2 TABLE*/ 
INSERT INTO tbl_address (Emp_id,Home_adrs,Home_number,Home_mailid,CHA_PHA_same,Contact_name,Relation,City,Contact_adrs,Contact_num)
VALUES     (@Emp_id,@Home_adrs,@Home_number,@Home_mailid,@CHA_PHA_same,@Contact_name,@Relation,@City,@Contact_adrs,@Contact_num)
SELECT @Emp_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
RETURN  
/* INSERTING INTO 3RD TABLE*/ 
INSERT INTO tbl_empeducation (Emp_id,Qualification,University_board,Specialization,Year_of_passing,Grade_cgpa)
VALUES     (@Emp_id,@Qualification,@University_board,@Specialization,@Year_of_passing,@Grade_cgpa)
SELECT @Emp_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
RETURN  

/* INSERTING INTO 4TH TABLE*/ 
INSERT INTO tbl_bank_account_dtls(Emp_id,Bank_name,Bank_adrs,Account_num,Ifsc_code,Name_of_acnt_holder)
VALUES(@Emp_id,@Bank_name,@Bank_adrs,@Account_num,@Ifsc_code,@Name_of_acnt_holder)
SELECT @Emp_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
RETURN  

/* INSERTING INTO 5TH TABLE*/ 
INSERT INTO tbl_Employment_hist(Emp_id,From_date,To_date,Organization,Job_title_his,Sal_per_mnth,Reasons_for_leavn,Reference_name,Contact_num_hist,Organization_ref,Job_title_ref)
VALUES      (@Emp_id,@From_date,@To_date,@Organization,@Job_title_his,@Sal_per_mnth,@Reasons_for_leavn,@Reference_name,@Contact_num_hist,@Organization_ref,@Job_title_ref)
SELECT @Emp_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
RETURN  

/*SELECT @identity AS Id*/

END


GO
```

Comment: Which one is getting the data? Also, try reducing this to a minimal re-create to be easier to follow.

Comment: first table is getting data

Answer (score 0):

Your SP contains multiple RETURN statements, and it will exit after the first one. The remainder will not be executed.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx

> RETURN (Transact-SQL)
>   Exits unconditionally from a query or procedure. RETURN is immediate and complete and can be used at any point to exit from a procedure, batch, or statement block. Statements that follow RETURN are not executed.

Comment: after correction ** The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__tbl_addre__Emp_i__6B64E1A4". The conflict occurred in database "ctsdev", table "dbo.tbl_empinfo ", column 'Emp_id'.
The statement has been terminated.**  this error is coming for the first table

Comment: That means that the row that you are trying to insert is referring to a record in another table, but that other table does not have such a record. You'll have to fix that yourself (check the relation, check the data, etc). We shouldn't try to solve that by adding comments to my answer, it is a different issue.